# Can't use opencv to read my ip camera video

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

Hello I am a beginner on opencv and I am trying to create an real time object detection program through a HIKVISION IP camera. Using RTSP but when I run the code I get this error

Ip_add is like `rtsp://login:password@ip_address:554/streaming/channels/101`

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(Ip_add, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

while True:
_, frame = cap.read()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(1400, 600))

(class_ids, scores, bboxes) = model.detect(frame)

for class_id, score, bbox in zip(class_ids, scores, bboxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = bbox
    cv2.putText(frame, classes[class_id], (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2,(200, 0, 50),2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (200, 0, 50), 2)
cv2.imshow("IP Camera", frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Sorry... this is the error i get :   [h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000021c7162b0c0] no frame!

Comment: Is it working with FFplay (shell command)? `ffplay rtsp://login:password@ip_address:554/streaming/channels/101`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly solved the problem by using `imutils` instead of `opencv` to read the real time video stream.

```
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils.video import VideoStream

rtsp_url = "rtsp://login:passzord@ipaddress/streaming/channels/101"
video_stream = VideoStream(rtsp_url).start()

while True:
frame = video_stream.read()
if frame is None:
    continue

frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=1200)

frame = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(1400, 600))


cv2.imshow('Ip Camera ', frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == ord('q'):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video_stream.stop()
```